# Is it possible to tie specific unit test to a hotkey in VS 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a function in C# and need to call specific unit test for this function dozens times a day.

I assigned a hotkey to "Debug Selected Tests" and it works as long as that unit test is selected. However, sometimes unit test becomes unselected and hotkey doesn't do anything, so I have to navigate to Test Explorer, find that unit test among dozens of others and select it again.

Is there a way to tie debugging of specific unit test to a hotkey so that it runs no matter if it is selected in Test Explorer? I imagine it would be some sort of command line like `testrunner.exe Mytest /debug` but I don't know if such functionality exists in Visual Studio.

Comment: You can use live unit testing instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/live-unit-testing?view=vs-2017. This automatically runs unit tests in the background as you change your code.

Comment: @Polyfun: this only works in Enterprise Edition of VS (I use Community Edition) and I need it to run on-demand.

Comment: The hotkeys `Crtl+R, D` run all tests that were run in your last test run, maybe that helps (if you don't run any other tests in between to often). Otherwise live unit testing would be the way to go.

Comment: @FeRaaC this works for me. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as such